# Process utilizes more than one core?

Tags: process, cpu, utilization

Having a dual-core CPU, I notice (on the Windows Task Manager) that some processes can take more than 50% CPU utilization. Knowing that each process can be executed in one cpu core at any given time, I'm expecting that it will utilize maximum 1/n of my n-core cpu. Note that my CPU is not HT capable. Do I misinterpret the value of CPU column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a process has multiple threads running, then you can use 100% of your CPU.

Each thread can use 100% of a single core, so you need N running threads in your process to use 100% of a N-core CPU.